# How to map the root path to a CGI script?

Tags: apache-2.2

I can map `/hg` on the server to `hgweb.cgi` using:

`ScriptAlias /hg "/home/user/webdir/hgweb.cgi"`

but how do I map `/` (the server root) to the CGI script?

**UPDATE**: Here is what worked for me:

1. Disable the default site using `sudo a2dissite default`
2. Create /etc/apache2/sites-available/hg with the following contents:

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName code.company.com
        ServerAlias code
        DocumentRoot /srv/hg/cgi-bin/

        <Directory "/srv/hg/cgi-bin/">
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                DirectoryIndex hgweb.cgi
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add AddHandler: AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
2. Add +ExecCGI: Options +ExecCGI
3. Change DirectoryIndex: DirectoryIndex hgweb.cgi